# PDF files still indexed when X-Robots-Tag noindex set in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, noindex, pdf

I am trying to analyse the *.htaccess* file of a website, specifically the following piece of code:

```
<FilesMatch ".pdf$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

It is supposed to **noindex all the PDF files of the website**.

However, the PDF files are still there up and running, and I am sure about it because:

- they still appear in SERPs
- they are green in search console
- the header check does not show any command about noindexing

How is that possible? My hypothesis is that there is some conflict in the *.htaccess* code.

The `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Disallow: /web_service/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Do you have a robots.txt file?  Could it be disallowing crawling of those files?  Google can't see the headers if it can't crawl.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller the robots.txt is file is as simple as possible, on purpose, and is not disallowing any PDF.  If you tell me I can link it, I will. Thank you

Comment: You can link.   Then we can check to see if your headers are actually getting set.

Comment: Thank you @StephenOstermiller : https://www.aurigaspa.com/robots.txt

Comment: Your header isn't making it to your documents.  I tried `curl --head 'https://www.aurigaspa.com/wp-content/uploads/Top-Banking-Trends-for-2019-and-How-Banks-Need-to-Prepare-White-Paper-Auriga.pdf'`

Comment: The directives you posted should ordinarily set the required header providing the `.pdf` file actually exists and the request is not internally rewritten to a script that manages the PDF response? The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required and should be removed (at least during testing). The `FilesMatch` regex should strictly be `"\.pdf$"` to match a literal dot and not _anything_. It's possible there is a conflict, although it's difficult to imagine what "conflict" that might be? Where is this `.htaccess` located? Is the `.htaccess` file being processed? Do you have other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Thank you @StephenOstermiller , where do you write those commands?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, thank you. Yours are all appropriate questions. Unfortunately I do not have direct access to the file as well as to the directories. However, I would like to ask you something else: who could possibly untangle this problem? Who am I supposed to hire?

Comment: [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is a command line program.  You can run it after SSHing into your server, or you can download and install it onto your home computer.

Comment: Thank you @StephenOstermiller. Anyway, I believe this problem is bigger than it looks like (you haven't seen the htaccess file...), so I'm wondering whether to hire someone to fix it. Is there anybody capable of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Your header isn't making it to your documents. I tried `curl --head 'https://www.aurigaspa.com/wp-content/uploads/Top-Banking-Trends-for-2019-and-How-Banks-Need-to-Prepare-White-Paper-Auriga.pdf'`  [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is a command line program.  You can run it yourself after SSHing into your server, or you can download and install it onto your home computer.

My guess is that `mod_headers` is either not installed or not enabled.  You have the condition `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` in your rules.   That will cause your directive to silently not work if mod_headers isn't installed or enabled.

I would suggest changing your .htaccess to:

```
<FilesMatch ".pdf$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
</FilesMatch>
```

That could make you website unavailable.   If that happens, you know you need to install or enable `mod_headers`.    See [How to install mod_headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/214054/how-to-install-mod-headers) on ServerFault.

Comment: THank you Stephen, I guess this was the problem indeed. Problem solved!